# Installing windows 11 fails, "A media driver your computer needs is missing" error

Tags: drivers, installation, windows-11, bootable-media

I've been trying to install win11 on my MSI Pulse laptop, but whenever I boot from USB it gives me error "A media driver your computer needs is missing". I found out so far that INTEL VMD/IRST is responsible for this error. It's an new intel tech to improve your NVME ssd life.

What I tried so far and didn't work:

1. Disabling VMD in BIOS
2. Disabling Secure boot (note, that on new laptops and motherboards for intel 11+ gen you can not use legacy boot mode (BIOS), you can only use UEFI mode)
3. Trying to put drivers on usb and selecting them when windows11 install gives me and error (I can pick drivers but windows installer gives me another error that the drives is already installed and no new version was found).

(After some time I managed to install windows11 and will provide a full instruction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **INSTRUCTION**

**It's required to use another windows PC to download drivers, so here is what you need to do on that other PC:**

1. Go to Microsoft site and download Windows Installation Media Tool (second download button) [link to microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows11)
2. Make a bootable windows11 USB-drive with this tool
3. **Create a new folder C:\FolderForDriver**
4. Download IRST driver for you new PC/laptop processor from intel site: [link for 10-11 gen CPU](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19512/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-10th-and-11th-gen-platforms.html) and [link for 11-13 gen CPU](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/720755/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-11th-up-to-13th-gen-platforms.html) **and put it in the C:\FolderForDriver**
5. Press Start (windows icon on the left bottom of your desktop)
6. Type Powershell (it will offer you Windows powershell app)
7. Right click on Windows powershell app and press **"Run as administrator"**
8. It will open blue screen, type the following ***cd C:\FolderForDriver*** and press Enter
9. Type **.\SetupRST.exe -extractdrivers C:\FolderForDriver\RST** and press Enter
10. Copy RST folder on some other USB-drive (this is important, I do not recommend copying it to a bootable USB with windows-11)
11. Insert both your USB-drives into you **new PC/laptop** and boot from windows11 USB-drive
12. It will give you same error that driver is missing, press ok and find driver folder on your second USB and select it.
13. Now it should install IRST driver without any problem and proceed to windows 11 installation.

Comment: This instruction assumes, that you already have Windows. Believe it or not, but I have just purchased laptop *without* OS and can not perform this insane mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: For me this was a red herring, caused by faulty installation media. The USB installer made from macOS with bananEtcher failed. When I copied the ISO to USB using Rufus inside a Windows 11 VM, the Windows 11 installer worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too when my boot media was plugged into a USB 3.0 port. I moved it to a USB 2.0 port and was able to continue with the installation.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I wanna tell is Windows really sucks! This thing made me sit like a chicken for almost one day.For me I was setting up a new build using new m2 ssd  with USB drive 3.1 for installing OS. Try the below to see if it working for you.

1. Use different USB port(If tried 3 then try 2)
2. Use different USB stick(If tried 3 then try 2)
3. Write the image using different tool
4. Try installing Intel ISRT driver or AMD raid driver during the windows installation setup

If you can't try all of these or none of them is worked you probably having the problem that I faced which was **Win 10/11 missing driver for USB 3**. Since I didn't had a USB 2, the solution I found out for this is,

Write a `Linux distribution`(ubuntu would do) to USB stick. Boot the OS live if u don't want to install, download/copy ISO, format new drive using `NTFS` using `gparted`, create a small partition like 10GB, simply copy or write using any tool(copy would do) the files inside ISO file to this partition, remove the stick, boot the PC from SSD itself, whola! you got working Windows Setup!

Answer (score 0):

I was using "dd" to write the ISO file to the flash stick. Using "rufus" (https://rufus.ie/en/) to write the ISO file fixed the issue.